# How to draw an unit circle using numpy and matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, geometry

I want to draw an unit circle(cos+sin), using numpy and matplotlib.
I wrote the following:

```
t = np.linspace(0,np.pi*2,100)
circ = np.concatenate((np.cos(t),np.sin(t)))
```

and I plotted, but failed.

```
ax.plot(t,circ,linewidth=1)
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`plot` does not do a parametric plot.  You must give it the `x` and `y` values, not `t`.

`x` is `cos(t)` and `y` is `sin(t)`, so give those arrays to `plot`:

```
ax.plot(np.cos(t), np.sin(t), linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use Circle (http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
circ = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=1, edgecolor='b', facecolor='None')
ax.add_patch(circ)
plt.show()
```